# Typescript promise type in then

Tags: typescript

Why in then block session is nullable and how to fix it?

[Typescript sandbox.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAGlC8UDeBLAJgLigZ2AJxQDsBzAGhwm2xQHtCslsBbYLXAkgXygB8pCArgBshnAFBiAxnVxQAHgEYE-CAHcoABTw0mKbBAA8MAHwAKPJRpCAbtHjHkYqM6gXsV26YDkzYAAsvKABDbCgBQgBrQhpVQmDQmABKMU5kp0UAOn8IQlNTAX08RPskJxdylAAzKFMAQgKIPAz9KlpCRKh-bXVCNSgAUTxtPG8ILzTy8oamluo6ZpYoAHolqBoIiUmXC2ABPDjpsudUo6gsvxz8wpLTqcLmyjnCBeBl1dU-EApWuig9fmEQiCACMhNAgsQgkQAPynE7lDKSILASR%20UwQexQCCJIA)

```
type X = {id: string, session: {smt: string} | null}

const x1 = new Promise<X>(resolve => {
    resolve('smth' as unknown as X)
})

x1.then((user)=>{
    if (!user.session) throw new Error('e')

    user.session.smt // ok

    return user
})
.then(user=>{
    user.session.smt // why session is nullable again?
})
.catch(e=> e)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TypeScript does not know that the user object hasn't been modified in the meantime. For instance, somebody else might have done:

```
x1.then((user)=>{
    user.session = null; // that's allowed
})
```

Comment: Oh, got it, so when i return i need to as {id: string, session: {smt: string} } to make it work :( Not very convenient...

Comment: You can create a type Y which has a non-nullable session property. After doing your validation or operations which guarantee some constraints you can return your object as Y in the then-callback.